# ASP.net Where should keep user Country Code when user come first time

Tags: asp.net

I need to store user Country Name and Country Code (based on IP Address) when user comes 1st time (on 1st request) so that I can use these information on other page to manage Shopping Cart.

For example if user come form different location I can show customize information (e.g Currency Symbol, different Amount of Item/Product).

Comment: Typically in Session state, and / or in a database ... can you be more specific please?

Comment: first you should be get IP Address and save Database and for next time check if IP Address Exist in database do not nothing

Comment: You should not be doing this via IP address. You should ask them their language preference the first time they enter your site, then store it in a cookie. What if I'm from the USA, but in Japan on vacation? I would want English, not Japanese, even if my IP address is from Japan.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Get IP Address and check if IP Address does not Exist, Save it in `database`. 
and for next times check if not exist save it.
belowe link explain get IP Address

```
      HttpRequest request = base.Request;

      // Get UserHostAddress property.
      string address = request.UserHostAddress;
      if(!Location.Check(address))
      {
       Location.Insert(address);
       }
```

If you want get location Based on IP Address you can use belowe API:

```
http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=<your_api_key>&ip=74.125.45.100&timezone=false
```

[Here's](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/118711-class-countryip-vbc%23/) an Example in both VB/C# for use this API

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Can you please explain 'Location' class which you used in your example. How should I manage this class? I like your solution. But my concern is about performance. For example, if user visit 30-40 pages for current session, then I need to hit DB 30-40 times to check it.


So, how should I manage this class? Should I use this approach at every page load or 'Session_Start'?